# Linux cc compilation of library in directory within project?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, libraries, cc

My directory structure looks like the following:

```
-xmllib
    -libxml++-1.0.a
-main.cc
```

..and I issue the command:

```
cc -lstdc++ -L./xmllib -llibxml++-1.0.a main.cc
```

But then it tells me that it can't find the binary for the library...even though I issued the command from the root directory.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibxml++-1.0.a main.cc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there any reason why cc can't find the binary library?

I'm using cc version 2.96 (yes, it's old).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
-llibxml++-1.0.a
```

to this:

```
-lxml++-1.0
```

On Posix, the linker's `-l` option wants neither the `lib` prefix or the `.a` extension.